# Where should type conversion for a form input occur -- before validation, as part of validation, or other?

Tags: design-patterns, validation, type-conversion

I have a HTML form that collects a series of numbers in text fields.

Logically I need to do the following, but I can't think of a way to structure it that is clean:

1. Retrieve values from form
2. Validate that the strings contain only numbers
3. Convert the values from strings to actual numbers
4. Validate that each number is in an allowed range

Either I'm doing type conversion inside my validate method and outputting type errors the same way a business rule error would be reported (which is what I want to do, since from the form perspective all validation errors need to be reported the same way). I don't like this because it seems wrong to change values inside of a validation method.

Or I have two validation methods, with the first verifying type but not mutating data, and the second one assuming the types are correct and doing business rule validaiton, with a mutation function between the two that runs only if the type validation passed, and coerces the strings to numbers.  I like the separation, but this seems a bit complicated.

I'm not really feeling that good about either of these options.  How is this problem usually solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... good question.

How about having a FormDataMapping class that takes in the string data from the form, converts it to strongly-typed data, and then uses that data to initialize a new instance of  a FormData class. The FormData class wouldn't be able to exist in an invalid state, so the constructor would validate all of the strongly-typed values and throw an exception if any value was invalid.

```
// Responsible for mapping string data to an actual FormData instance
public class FormDataMapper
{
    public FormData CreateFormData(string percentText)
    {
        float percent = float.Parse(percent);

        return new FormData(percent);
    }
}

// Responsible for always being in a valid state
public class FormData
{
    public Percent { get; private set; }

    public FormData(float percent)
    {
        if(percent < 0 || percent > 100)
        {
            throw new ArgumentInvalidException("Percent must be between 0 and 100", "percent");
        }

        this.Percent = percent;
    }
}
```

If you plan on doing live javascript validation, that's another issue entirely. You can have a separate stage of validation for that. Remember that that's *technically* just the implementation of the view. The fact that you tell the user they've entered invalid data doesn't have anything to do with your application's validation logic. Instead, this is just a convenience to the user (an almost required convenience now days). :)